# How can I prevent an executable icon from appearing in the dock?

Tags: macos, gcc, compilation, sublimetext3

I need to modify the source code of this program to prevent the icon from appearing in the macOS's dock when it is run. It generates an Unix executable. I'm not aware of developing programs for macOS.

The main problem is that a third program (Sublime text) runs that program. And if Sublime Text is full screen, it goes back to the main desktop.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>


@interface NSColor (NSColorHexadecimalValue)
@end

@implementation NSColor (NSColorHexadecimalValue)

// NSColorHexadecimalValue from http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1576/_index.html
-(NSString *)hexValue {
  CGFloat redFloatValue, greenFloatValue, blueFloatValue;
  int redIntValue, greenIntValue, blueIntValue;
  NSString *redHexValue, *greenHexValue, *blueHexValue;

  // Convert the NSColor to the RGB color space before we can access its components
  NSColor *convertedColor = [self colorUsingColorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace];

  if(convertedColor) {
    // Get the red, green, and blue components of the color
    [convertedColor getRed:&redFloatValue green:&greenFloatValue blue:&blueFloatValue alpha:NULL];

    // Convert the components to numbers (unsigned decimal integer) between 0 and 255
    redIntValue=redFloatValue*255.99999f;
    greenIntValue=greenFloatValue*255.99999f;
    blueIntValue=blueFloatValue*255.99999f;

    // Convert the numbers to hex strings
    redHexValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", redIntValue];
    greenHexValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", greenIntValue];
    blueHexValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", blueIntValue];

    // Concatenate the red, green, and blue components' hex strings together
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", redHexValue, greenHexValue, blueHexValue];
  }
  return nil;
}

// color from hex found from http://www.karelia.com/cocoa_legacy/Foundation_Categories/NSColor__Instantiat.m
+ (NSColor *)colorFromHex:(NSString *)inColorString {
  NSColor *result = nil;
  unsigned int colorCode = 0;
  unsigned char redByte, greenByte, blueByte;

  if ([inColorString length] == 3) {
    NSString *newColor = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@",
      [inColorString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,1)],
      [inColorString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,1)],
      [inColorString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(1,1)],
      [inColorString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(1,1)],
      [inColorString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(2,1)],
      [inColorString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(2,1)]];
    inColorString = [newColor autorelease];
  }

  if (nil != inColorString) {
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:inColorString];
    (void) [scanner scanHexInt:&colorCode]; // ignore error
  }
  redByte   = (unsigned char) (colorCode >> 16);
  greenByte = (unsigned char) (colorCode >> 8);
  blueByte  = (unsigned char) (colorCode);  // masks off high bits
  result = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:(float)redByte / 0xff
                                     green:(float)greenByte/ 0xff
                                      blue:(float)blueByte / 0xff
                                     alpha:1.0];
  return result;
}

@end

@interface Picker : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate> {
  NSColorPanel *panel; // weak ref
}

- (void)show;
- (void)writeColor;
- (void)exit;

@end

@implementation Picker

- (void)show {
  // setup panel and its accessory view

  NSView *accessoryView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:(NSRect){{0, 0}, {220, 30}}];

  NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:(NSRect){{110, 4}, {110 - 8, 24}}];
  [button setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
  [button setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
  button.title = @"Pick";
  button.action = @selector(writeColor);
  button.target = self;

  NSButton *cancelButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:(NSRect){{8, 4}, {110 - 8, 24}}];
  [cancelButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
  [cancelButton setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
  cancelButton.title = @"Cancel";
  cancelButton.action = @selector(exit);
  cancelButton.target = self;

  [accessoryView addSubview:[button autorelease]];
  [accessoryView addSubview:[cancelButton autorelease]];

  panel = [NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel];
  [panel setDelegate:self];
  [panel setShowsAlpha:NO]; // TODO: support for rgba() output values
  [panel setAccessoryView:[accessoryView autorelease]];
  [panel setDefaultButtonCell:[button cell]];

  // load user settings
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *color = [defaults stringForKey:@"startColor"];
  if (color != nil) {
    [panel setColor:[NSColor colorFromHex:color]];
  }
  [panel setMode:[defaults integerForKey:@"mode"]]; // will be 0 if not set, which is NSGrayModeColorPanel

  // show panel
  [panel makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
  //[NSApp runModalForWindow:panel]; // resets panel position
}

- (void)writeColor {
  NSString *hex = [panel.color hexValue];

  // save color and current mode to defaults
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setObject:hex forKey:@"startColor"];
  [defaults setInteger:panel.mode forKey:@"mode"];
  [defaults synchronize]; // force a save since we are exiting

  // write color to stdout
  NSFileHandle *stdOut = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardOutput];
  [stdOut writeData:[hex dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

  [self exit];
}

- (void)exit {
  [panel close];
}

// panel delegate methods

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
  [NSApp terminate:self];
}

// application delegate methods

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
  ProcessSerialNumber psn = {0, kCurrentProcess};
  TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);
  SetFrontProcess(&psn);
  [self show];
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
  app.delegate = [[[Picker alloc] init] autorelease];
  [app run];
  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

It shows an icon like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication`:

```
TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);
```

*Try* `kProcessTransformToUIElementApplication`:

```
TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToUIElementApplication);
```

I believe that only `UIElementApplication` can hide it's own dock icon.